# Hibernate ManyToMany delete/remove entity Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I have a ManyToMany relationship between 2 entities.

Author -> author_books <- Books. 
With a total of 3 tables.

Here below the code:

```
@Entity
public class Author

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "author_id")
private Long author_id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Author_Books", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
private List<Books> books;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Books")
public class Books

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "book_id")
private Long book_id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
@NotNull
private List<Author> authors;
```

Now when I try to do the following I get the following error:

**BooksDao.delete(books);**
\n
ERROR: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lucytest`.`author_books`, CONSTRAINT `FK_d7blldnja6fa73ktxehccduq` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `Books` (`book_id`))

I search the whole web and stack overflow but can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated also for anyone else have this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get this working by deleting all the tables in MySQL and letting hibernate create them from scratch only this time with the following code:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "Author_Books", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
    @Valid
    private List<Books> books;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(name = "Author_Books", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
    @Valid
    private List<Author> authors;
```

I hope this will save everybody the headache it caused me.